# Vuejs Select Dropdown writing an option thats not present makes selected value null

Tags: javascript, vue.js, select, input, dropdown

I am trying to use the VueJs Select component (https://vue-select.org) but what I want to achieve is having the user to write an option on the input field that is not on the presented defaulted options.

When I write into the text field it shows no results, and the handler of selected option tells me that the value is null, why is that?

Here is my v-select:

```
<v-select :options="sortingOptions" v-model="sortingDefinition" taggable @input="setSelected" :multiple="false"></v-select>
```

I passed taggable as property because it tells on the documentation the following:

*To allow input that's not present within the options, set the taggable prop to true.* (https://vue-select.org/guide/values.html#tagging)

Then when I start typing something and end, then stop the focus on the input (dropdown) field, the following function is not triggered with the new value that I typed why?

```
setSelected(value){
        console.log('value: ', value);
},
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have to press Enter after typing the option I want, didn't know about this, I thought losing focus would be enough.